# Camunda h2 database persistence

Tags: camunda

We are using camunda-bpm-jboss-7.1.0-Final in our java web project. The UI part is created using jsf and the database is mysql.

However, camunda comes with default h2 database, which does not persists data.

Each time we turn the jboss server off, we loose some process -id's.So my question is, is there a way to configure the h2 database, so that it persists data?

Answer (score 1):

camunda currently supports H2, MySQL, PostgreSQL, DB2, Oracle and MSSQL. If you don't want to use the default H2 configuration you can change the data source in your JBoss configuration. Please see the installation guide: http://docs.camunda.org/latest/guides/installation-guide/jboss/#bpm-platform-install-the-platform-on-a-vanilla-jboss-creating-a-datasource

Comment: Hi
we already have h2 configured in standalone.xml. My question is-
1. h2 is losing all data on shutting down the jboss server, is there a way to make it persist all data?
2. We have used our customised database mysql, but camunda is still pointing to h2. Is it possible to point camunda completely to our own database?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simply change your JDBC connection string to :

> jdbc:h2:file:full-path-to-file

***nix:**

> jdbc:h2:file:/tmp/my-database-file

**Windows:**

> jdbc:h2:file:C:/data/test

For more information, see: http://www.h2database.com/html/faq.html#database_files